# System.Windows.Forms.Binding and empty textboxes

Tags: c#, binding, textbox

I have specified a System.Windows.Forms.Binding for a textbox on my form. I have set the DataSourceNullValue property of the binding to 'DBNull.Value' and the NullValue property to 'string.Empty'. The DataSourceUpdateMode is set to 'OnValidation'. Everything works fine except one thing: when the textbox is bound to a datasource which has NULL set for the field the textbox is bound to and I enter the (empty) textbox and leave it (without changing anything), the datasource is updated from NULL to an empty string.

At [MSDN - Binding.NullValue Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.nullvalue.aspx) I have found, that the NullValue property is ignored for String-datatypes.

The desired behaviour is that the value in the datasource should stay NULL if the textbox is empty. How could I achieve this?